# What does "sort anything that looks like a number as a number" actually mean?

Tags: excel

This has been bugging me for years. What does the Excel "sort anything that looks like a number as a number" actually mean?

When I try to sort in Excel a column consisting mainly of numbers, I get the message:

```
Sort Warning: 
The following sort key may not sort as expected
because it contains some numbers formatted as text: 
DateValue

What would you like to do?

() Sort anything that looks like a number, as a number 
() Sort numbers and numbers stored as text separately
```

Can anyone explain exactly what the difference is between these two options?

Comment: It means that cells containing numerical-only text will be converted to numbers and sorted. The second option only sorts cells formatted as numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel sorts numbers differently than text, for example {2,10}:

When sorted by number it will return

```
2
10
```

When sorted as text it will be:

```
10
2
```

This because when sorting as text excel goes character by character and sorts on that and since 1 comes before 2 it will be put first.

The number sort looks at the whole number and since 2 is less than 10 it comes first.